# PySimpleGui change whole layout based menu clicked

Tags: python, menu, window, pysimplegui

I've made simple GUI for my python script and I don't want to use Tabs or TabGroups [tabs github example](https://github.com/amithr/PySimpleGUI---Tabs/blob/main/main_window.py)

I added own menu and items, but not found any solutions to change layout based on menu item clicks. So is there any quick and nice solution to change layout based menu item click?

```
menu_def = ['Layout', ['Layout1::LAYOUT1_KEY', 'Layout2::LAYOUT2_KEY', 'Layout3::LAYOUT3_KEY']],['About',['About::ABOUT_KEY']]
```

Here is the example layouts and window call.

```
layout1_layout = [
    [sg.Text("Layout 3 text")]
]

layout2_layout = [
    [sg.Text("Layout 2 text.")]
]

window = sg.Window("Example form", layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, margins=(250,100)).read()
```

Comment: There is a Demo Program that shows how to do this.  Here's an eCookbook one that shows the same kind of thing:
https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/layouts/swapping-window-layouts
Where you get the event that triggers that change doesn't matter. Menu, Button, Checkbox, .... those are simply your "if" statements. Inside them is where you do the swap and the code is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Column element for your layout1, layout2 in same row, but only one layout with option `visible=True`, all others with option `visible=False`, also record which layout is visible now.

When click which layout in menu, Set visible layout to be invisible and set which layout you click to be visible and record this layout visible now.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_def = [['Layout', ['Layout1', 'Layout2']]]

font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout1 = [[sg.Text("Layout 1 text")]]
layout2 = [[sg.Text("Layout 2 text")]]

layout = [
    [sg.Menu(menu_def, key='MENU')],
    [sg.Column(layout1, key='COL1'),
     sg.Column(layout2, key='COL2', visible=False)],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

col, col1, col2 = 1, window['COL1'], window['COL2']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == 'Layout1' and col != 1:
        col = 1
        col1.update(visible=True)
        col2.update(visible=False)
    elif event == 'Layout2' and col != 2:
        col = 2
        col2.update(visible=True)
        col1.update(visible=False)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, something wrong with my GUI, because I choose any menu item or press any button a whole GUI and console shutdown.

Comment: Maybe you miss the `while` loop to read and handling of event.